# Google maps in the role of navigator

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-mobile

guys!
I have follow question.

I am writing an application that will track movement of user + other options.
I plan to use Google maps for this.
I assume to send in some way gps coordinates to the google maps server. 
The question is do I need to be always re-initialize and load the map.

It would be nice to do it without restarting.
Because this application is mobile I would like to avoid a lot of traffic and have a quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish with this app? From your question

> do I need to be always re-initialize and load the map

it seems you're thinking about accessing the Google Maps website directly. The ideal way to write an application would be to use the [Google Maps APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html). It also depends if you're developing your application to Android, iOS or a completely different beast. For Android you can take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html). To avoid a lot of traffic, you can build a [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197325/what-is-backend-and-frontend-programming) that your mobile app would talk to.

Comment: In my case it is completely different beast! I solved problem using setCenter method of google maps object